APK network calls bypass emulator's proxy
(with Android Studio 2023.2.1)
Forgive the extreme naivety of my question but there must be a simple concept that I'm missing, because everything seems correct from my perspective.

I am trying to explore the network calls of some app on my smartphone.
To do so, I thought I'd run the APK on an emulator and setup some interceptor on my computer.
Specifically, I've installed the APK onto a virtual device in Android Studio.
Then I've installed Postman and enabled its "interceptor" feature, i.e. some embedded proxy listening at 127.0.0.1:5559
Finally, I went into Android Studio's settings and under "HTTP Proxy" I've chosen "Manual proxy configuration" > HTTP > Host name 127.0.0.1, Port number 5559

When I click the "check connection" button of Android Studio's proxy settings panel and enter any url (e.g. google.com) then I see the connection attempt appear in Postman's interceptor proxy's logs. Success!
However, subsequently, none of the calls made by the app itself generate any entry in the proxy.
So, what am I missing? Is there a specific Android Studio configuration that makes the apps able to bypass the proxy? Am I being really dumb? (for example : is it obvious for everyone else but me that if the virtual device is set to use its "Wifi" then Android Studio's proxy setting gets ignored? Something similar?)
Please note : I also tried changing Windows' Internet Options -- I have set a proxy for the entirety of the OS (and I've made sure that "Don't use the proxy server for local addresses" box is NOT ticked). Same scenario! The App is able to jump over it entirely! How?

Apparently proxy settings on Android do not automatically apply system wide - unlike setting a VPN. Here's a list of apps creating on-device VPNs with support for proxies.
